# Regex allow sequence to end right in the middle

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regex that would match any string containing only the '0' and '1' char as long as it does not contain the specific sequence "00" or "010".

My idea was something like this
1*(011+)*

But a problem shows up, if the string ended with a 0, like 1110, then it should be valid. With my regex, any 0 has to be followed by two or more ones, but I can't figure out how to make this specific exception.

I need a regex that would force any 0 to be followed by two or more ones OR to end. This would allow sequences ending in 0 and 01, in addition to the obvious "ends with 1" case where, as in "111111", the unautorized sequences are not present.

How can I "cut off short" a condition in a regex, allowing it to either go on according to my rules, or to end right there?

Comment: Use [`^(?![01]*01?0)[10]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/hxuCjh/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix your regex like this:

```
1*(011+)*(01?)?
```

Add an (optional) group at the end that matches incomplete zero groups, i.e. `0` and `01`.